# Undefined reference: переменная extern

Tags: c, ос, компоновщик

Я решил написать небольшую ОС, т.к. интересно, как они работают. Нашел туториал на wiki.osdev.org, вроде все было нормально, но потом я начал сам писать менеджер памяти. Я компилирую код на С и компоную с помощью gcc (кросс-компилятор i686-elf-gcc, Mac), ассемблер с NASM. Вот отрывок кода, на который ругается:

```
void init_heap()
{
    extern uint16_t kernel_heap;
    uint16_t *ge = &kernel_heap;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        pg[i].frbytes = 16380;
        pg[i].offset = ge + (PAGE_SIZE * i); //PAGE_SIZE = 16384, pg - массив структур page
/*
   typedef struct 
{
  uint16_t frbytes;
  uint16_t offset;
}
*/
    }
```

... (там дальше код, затем скобка закрывается)
Переменная kernel_heap объявлена в другом файле, heap.asm:

```
section .heap:
kernel_heap:
resb 65536
```

Ошибок во время компиляции нет, но при компоновке вылазит:
arch/i386/memory.o: In function `init_heap':
$HOME/Golub/kernel/arch/i386/memory.c:96: undefined reference to`kernel_heap' (это точно после компоновки)
При этом, если не производить никаких операций с ge, то ОС спокойно запускается.
Прошу помочь, т.к. мне нужно, чтобы offset каждого элемента массива pg хранила в себе адрес (адрес переменной + размер страницы * индекс)

Answer (score 2):

> C ... NASM

1. Для того, чтобы имя было доступно вне модуля `heap.asm`, оно должно быть объявлено как `global`
2. C ожидает, что внешние имена начинаются с подчёркивания. В самом исходнике на C этих подчёркиваний нет (компилятор преобразует имена автоматически), но в случае ассемблера их нужно добавлять вручную.

Поэтому:

```
global _kernel_heap
_kernel_heap:
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий.